# HTTP POST from desktop shortcut?

Tags: windows, http, post, shortcut-file

I've got a wireless router with the Tomato custom firmware on it. There are a number of actions I'd like to perform from simple desktop shortcuts, such as turning off the wireless or running a command for checking the status of the FTP server on it.

I can do these from the 'system' tool which lets you execute shell commands and returns the output.

I have found from analysis of the markup on this page that this is done by way of a simple XMLHttp POST to `shell.cgi`, parameters `action=execute&command=ls` and the output is the STDOUT you'd get if you performed this on a local shell.

How can I create a desktop shortcut to perform these posts and somehow echo the response?

What I have figured I could do so far is to make an HTML file which launches a POST using jQuery using some predefined function depending on URI segments, which I'd vary for each of the shortcut files.

However does anyone know a better way of doing this programatically under Windows?

Comment: Not many questions around here that I upvote AND vote for closing. Well done! It's a good question, but it doesn't belong here. Should be on Superuser (or just wait for the community to move it, only a few more votes)

Comment: I did think that after I posted it, I was in two minds about here or SU. I've just realised that the same origin policy is stopping me POST'ing to the router from these .htm files on my desktop with jQuery. So I guess my one idea is out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use wget, which has a windows port. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

```
wget --post-data 'action=execute&command=ls' http://router/shell.cgi
```

You can run the command from a batch file on your desktop.

Comment: I suspect this would be a solution could I get wget to SSL handshake with my router. I will accept this although a non-native solution is probably not the true optimal, I just have yet to find one at all :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is just a trick to do the same.**

1. Create a File like `executeThisPostRequest.sh`
2. Add the following lines in that file

   `curl --data "userName=Dileep&MyPassword=SameAsYours" http://10.0.1.1/login?`
   `exit`
3. Navigate to the File path where `executeThisPostRequest.sh` is located using terminal.
4. Execute chmod `a+x shellscript.execute.sh`
5. Right click on the file and select execute using terminal.

   `Open with >> Other >> all Application >> Utilities >> Terminal`

   ***Remember settings if you want.***

> Now you you can click on that file to execute a post request to the
>   URL with the data you have specified.